# Dead icons in Ubuntu Dock

Tags: gnome, gtk, 21.04, gtk3, glade

I am using Glade to develop a Gtk-3.0 app, in which the exit button (e.g. the window delete-event) does not destroy the application (on purpose, so I can hide it instead and run it in the background).

Now, if I use the glade-previewer to preview my window and subsequently press the exit button, the window closes and it looks like the glade-previewer process is killed, but somehow started again directly after. So everytime I use the glade-previewer, I get a new 'dead' icon in my Ubuntu dock, where the tooltip says 'glade-previewer'.

After exiting Glade, these supposedly running processes (icons) stay there indefinitely, as no context menu appears if I right click on them, therefore I can't close them. I searched my running processes and didn't find any process that corresponds to these icons. `pgrep glade-previewer` or `killall glade-previewer` don't find the processes.

[image: Dead Icons]

The only way to get rid of these icons AFAIK right now is to log out.

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 with gnome-shell 3.38.4. My Glade version is 3.38.2.

Any suggestions?